# How create a new queue

Tags: c, struct, queue

I'm new in programming C. I try to program a lot to become better :) 
But at the moment i got stuck at a stupid point.

I have a task to create a priority-queue. I got this both structs at the beginning.

```
struct q_elem_s {
char* name;
int priority;
struct q_elem_s *next;
};

struct PrioQueue {
int size;       //size of the queue
q_elem *root; //Beginn of the queue
};
```

Normaly I have no problems with a queue but I get confused from the second struct.

So my idea:

```
PrioQueue* pqueue_new() {
q_elem = malloc(sizeof(q_elem_s));
return NULL;
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly there are several mistakes in your code.
I here explain you what the second structure means and what should the correct function to create a new priority queue is. 
I have also introduced necessary changes in your code.

The first structure defines a single node in your queue.
While the second structure represents a single queue -

```
struct PrioQueue {
  int size;       //size of the queue
  struct q_elem_s *root; //Beginn of the queue
};
```

struct q_elem_s * root is the head node or the root node.

Your function should look like -

```
struct PrioQueue* pqueue_new() {
    struct PrioQueue *queue = malloc(sizeof(struct PrioQueue));
    queue->root = NULL;
    return queue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `pqueue_new` has two tasks: It allocates memory for a prio queue struct and it initalises the new struct. The new struct should be empty, that is its size is tero and it doesn't have any nodes yet. The returned value must be the handle to the new prio queue:

```
PrioQueue* pqueue_new() {
    PrioQueue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));

    if (q) {
        q->size = 0;
        q->root = NULL;
    }

    return q;
}
```

Things to note:

- Your current code doesn't have a type `PrioQueue`, only `struct PrioQueue`. You can usen `tyedef` to make `PrioQueue` a synonym for ´struct PrioQueue`.
- The function can return `NULL` when allocation fails. That means that it is the calling code's task to check the returned pointer.
- Note that you have two types of objects: The queue nodes and the holding structure, the queue itself. There's one queue object and zero to many node objects for each queue.
- Allocation of queue nodes will only take place when you push something to the queue. An empty queue does not have any nodes.
- You should also write a matching `pqueue_delete`, which cleans up all nodes and frees the memory allocated for the queue itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.